# wget keep session equivalence curl

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am creating a script which should be working also in MAC and I would like to know the equivalence of the following command line using curl command :

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookies.txt --referer=website.com http://website.com/folder/$count
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e website.com http://website.com/folder/$count
```

Comment: Yeps, contrary to how wget works, curl will always load and save session cookies unless you explicitly ask it to skip them (on load with --junk-session-cookies).